# Are the following outer measures?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have to check, if the following is an outer measures and if so, then determine the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}(\mu^*)=\{A \subseteq X: A \text{ is } \mu^*\text{ - measurable }\}$.

Fix some set $X$ and take $x,y\in X$ with $x \neq y$.
Let $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu^*(A)=1$ for $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)\backslash \{\emptyset\}$.

This is how far I have come:

I would say it is an outer measure, because the emptyset has measure zero and monotonicity is also fulfilled. For the $\sigma$-subadditivity, I thought that $\mu^*(\bigcup A_n)$ is always 1 (if we assume the sequence is not the sequence of the empty sets) and thus it has to be less or equal to $\sum \mu^* (A_i)$ because at least on of them is not empty. How can I determine the $\sigma$-algebra?
We defined $\mu^*$-measurability as the following:
$A \subseteq X$ is $\mu^*$-measurable if $\mu^*(Q)=\mu^*(Q \cap A)+\mu^*(Q \cap A^C) \forall Q \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\emptyset \subsetneq A \subsetneq X$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, pick $x\in A,y\in A^C$ set $Q=\{x,y\}$

$\mu^*(Q)=1, \mu^*(Q \cap A)+\mu^*(Q \cap A^C)=\mu^*(\{x\})+\mu^*(\{y\})=2$. So only $\emptyset, X$ are measurable.